# Calculate Kafka topic partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an n node Kafka cluster with just 2 topics
I have replicated the topics across all n nodes
I 'think' I have just a single consumer in the form of a mirrormaker consuming all topics although I intend to increase that from 1 to n mirror makers 
How many partitions should my topics use ? 1 then later n?

Answer (score 0):

The number of nodes in your cluster (what you call "n") should be independent of the number of partitions in a topic (let's call that "p"). The max number of consumers in a consumer group (Mirror Maker or any other single group) will be p, but the number you actually need will be entirely driven by your throughput performance and message ordering requirements.

Comment: I don't think I have message ordering requirements

Comment: Perhaps someone could expand on 'throughout requirements'